Why not BIDMSA rather than BIDMAS?
I feel this question is trivial, but still I wanted to present because I see it causing some problem at math education at primary school level. It is actually a question related to math education and its ease in the sense of securing it from causing unwarranted mistakes at root levels in mathematics.
I was following math lessons given to my daughter at primary school, they are teaching the sequence of operation as BIDMAS
with a note that Division and Multiplication are actually on a par but must be solved as they appear in expression from left to right, and the same for Addition and Subtraction. So, this means that the rule doesn't denote a strict sequence depending on the operation themselves but sometimes the positioning of those operators matters.
Now why not simply BIDMSA and we stress on the precedence by operations only irrespective of their position in expressions. So, only the nature of operations themselves determines their precedence, no need to check their positions in making precedences.

Is BIDMSA with strict ordering by operators, equivalent to BIDMAS with its operator\position precedence ruling. Or would that differ at extensions to higher fields of mathematics??

For history BIDMAS did cause a lot of dyscalculations because many schools unfortunately doesn't teach (or is not stressed enough) the students about the precedence by position part of the of rule, so the student (rightly! as taught) would solve $ 4 - 7 + 3$ as $4-10=-6.$ Students would remember and follow what they see, and what they are seeing is AS that is addition preceding subtraction, the positional rule from left to right is not written in the expressions BIDMAS, so it tends to be forgotten or overlooked which is a bad thing to reach at primary level, since mistakes at such level die hard. If one should insistent to keep BIDMAS then it should be written like BI(DM)(AS), I think the brackets would serve to ignite the memory of the student that there is a positioning argument for those. But anyhow, if BIDMSA is equivalent, then I see much simpler.

Pharaphrasing a five year old comment on this site: BIDMAS, SHMIDMAS, all these abbreviations are evil.

@JochenGlueck I don't agree that these mnemonics are "evil", but without discussion, they definitely can lead to problems.

...because one can pronounce BIDMAS (but not BIDMSA).

@SueVanHattum "bid-meh-sah!" :P

Related: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/12080/3593

Danica McKellar suggested the mnemonic "Pandas Eat: Mustard on Dumplings, and Apples with Spice" to emphasize that M and D have the same precedence, as do A and S.

When teaching the order of operations to students, I think that it is very important to emphasize the following:

The entire idea of the order of operations is that we want to be able to write down expressions and be sure that future readers will be able to interpret those expressions exactly as we intended.  The goal is clear and effective communication.
In order to clearly communicate ideas, the mathematical community has, over the years, agreed that certain operations take precedence over other operations:  multiplication takes priority over addition, exponentiation take priority over multiplication, and anything which has been intentionally grouped together takes priority over everything else.  This is a convention, and is not anything innate to mathematics itself.

Several years ago, in response to a different question about "exceptions" to the order of operations mnemonics, I wrote

Typically, when I teach order of operations, I use the phrase "GEMDAS," where the "G" stands for "grouping symbols" or "groups". ... If you insist on "PEMDAS" and further insist that "P" stands for "parenthses" and nothing else, then you get exceptions, I suppose. But I think that rather emphasizes the letter of the law over the spirit.

I have revised that thinking in the last couple of years, after teaching more remedial / high school level classes.  At this moment in time, I typically teach

subtraction is "just" addition of the additive inverse (i.e. addition of the opposite number),

division is "just" multiplication by the multiplicative inverse (i.e. multiplication by the reciprocal), and

the order of operations is GEMA (groups, exponents, multiplication, addition).


I really emphasize the first two, and spend time making sure that students grok the ideas in isolation (with reference to the commutative and associative properties of the operations) before worrying about more complicated expressions where an order of operations is going to matter.
After students are comfortable with expressions only involving strings of one operation, the general philosophy is something like the following: to simplify an expression, first convert all subtractions to addition and all division to multiplication (respecting groupings, e.g. $4-2(3+9\div 2)$ means $4+(-(2(3+9\cdot\tfrac{1}{2})))$), and then simplify the expression using the order of operations.
And then I tell students that if they want to be really clear, they should just use more parentheses.
Of course, if you insist on using one of the more traditional mnemonics, you can get a little meta and use parentheses, noting that anything in parentheses should be given the same priority, evaluating from left-to-right:  BI(DM)(AS), PE(MD)(AS), etc.

I like your emphasis on 4 stages in the basic arithmetic order of operations. But I disagree with the translation advice, because in practice people don't write that way -- it's an anti-simplifying step. Better to get rid of all the parenthesis and collapse signs in the multiply/divide step, and separately have proficiency with signs in the add/subtract step. Hence by blog on Automatic Negatives.

... In my college remedial courses I found that students who have been trained the way suggested above have a takeaway of "always swap paired signs" (or as they'll say, "keep change change") and wind up writing things like $5 + (-8) = 5 - (+8)$ and $4 + (+6) = 4-(-6)$ and so forth.

@DanielR.Collins I am surprised to hear that people don't write that way---I always turn subtraction into addition of the opposite (it is a coping strategy I found that really, really helps with my dyscalculia).  With respect to division, what I actually tend to model (after getting past the first few days) is regrouping things into denominators, but that comes after a discussion of arithmetic with rational numbers (which comes a little later in the course).

“This is a convention, and is not anything innate to mathematics itself.”  Or, to put it another way, it's part of the language of mathematics, a convention of how we write it down, and not inherent to how we do calculations.  (You could just as easily have an alternative language with different associativity, and everything would still work — as long as you knew which language you were working in!)
